# Hacer [google-spreadsheets] sinónimo de [google-hoja-de-cálculo]

Tags: soporte, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

[google-hoja-de-calculo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hoja-de-calculo) (sin acento) tiene 51 preguntas. Cuando se creó no era posible usar acentos en las etiquetas por lo que solicito en primer lugar:

- renombrar la etiqueta [google-hoja-de-calculo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hoja-de-calculo) a [google-hoja-de-cálculo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hoja-de-c%c3%a1lculo)

para lo cual se requiere el apoyo de los mods ♦.

Cabe mencionar que [google-spreadsheets](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets) tiene sólo 7 preguntas. Considero que lo que procede es hacer el sinónimo en lugar de sólo sustituir la etiqueta pues en SO se usa `[google-spreadsheets]` y en Web Applications dicha etiqueta es sinónimo de `[google-sheets]`.

Recién sugerí el sinónimo, hacen falta los votos de los usuarios con 5 puntos en la etiqueta pero somos muy pocos los que contamos con ellos y algunos de no participan de forma usual, por lo que incluyo de una vez la solicitud para

- hacer [google-spreadsheets](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets) sinónimo de [google-hoja-de-cálculo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hoja-de-c%c3%a1lculo)

Comment: Yo ya voté a favor. No quedan más usuarios que puedan votar.

Comment: Gracias Mariano.